# Sorting list of list based on Inner List's Multiple Integer elements

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort the list of list based on the two factors:

- PRIMARILY: list has to be sorted in ascending order based on the second element of each list in the list
- If there are cases wheres various list has same second elements then for those particular lists sorting has to be done in ascending order based on first element.

`data_input: [ [78, 10], [130, 0], [10, 1], [100, 100], [2, 2], [1, 99], [100, 0] ]`

for sorting based on first criterion I am using this code

```
data_input.sort(key= lambda x: x[1])
```

but cannot think of any way to implement second criterion as well

**Desired output  :**

- data_input: [ **[100, 0]**, **[130, 0]**, [10, 1], [2, 2], [78, 10], [1, 99], [100, 100] ]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to specify the order in which items  from the sublists must be fetched:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(data_input, key=itemgetter(1,0))
# [[100, 0], [130, 0], [10, 1], [2, 2], [78, 10], [1, 99], [100, 100]]
```

Comment: is `key=itemgetter(1,0)` is sorting the list first on the basis of `1` index of inner list then `0` index?

Comment: Yes that's right @aman

Comment: using this method and for this particular example, how can I sort the first element in reverse order that is descending order?

Comment: For this purpose you'd need a lambda function, and you'd have to take the negative of the first item so that it is sorted in inverse order

Answer (score 2):

Use a tuple as `key` argument to `sorted`:

```
data_input = [ [78, 10], [130, 0], [10, 1], [100, 100], [2, 2], [1, 99], [100, 0] ]

print(sorted(data_input, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
# [[100, 0], [130, 0], [10, 1], [2, 2], [78, 10], [1, 99], [100, 100]]
```

This basically asks Python to sort by `x[1]` and for same `x[1]`, sort by `x[0]`.

Comment: Could you please explain how `key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])` is working?

Comment: `key` argument of `sorted` can be used to tell on what basis you need the sort to take place. `(x[1], x[0])` part tells to sort by `x[1]` (second element in each sublist) and for same matching `x[1]`s (same second elements), sort by `x[0]` (first element in each sublist.

Comment: @ Austin for this particular example how can I sort first elements in  descending order (keeping second element as primary for sorting in ascending order)

Comment: Use: `key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0])`.